# How to distinct by multiple columns with input parameter in Linq

Tags: c#, oracle, linq

i have tre tables T020_CLIENTI,T021_SITI,T520_REL_STRUMENTI_SITI that i would join and then distinct by T020.Ragione_sociale,T520.DA_DATA,T520.A_DATA but obtain as return parameters T020.Ragione_sociale,T020.id_cliente,T520.cod_stumento,T520.DA_DATA,T520.A_DATA

my tables are

```
public partial class T020_CLIENTI
{
    public decimal ID_CLIENTE { get; set; }
    public Nullable<decimal> ID_COMUNE { get; set; }
    public Nullable<decimal> ID_CONSORZIO { get; set; }
    public string COD_LINEA_ATTIVITA { get; set; }
}

 public partial class T021_SITI 
{
    public decimal ID_SITO { get; set; }
    public Nullable<decimal> ID_FORNITORE { get; set; }
    public Nullable<decimal> ID_CLIENTE { get; set; }
}
public partial class T520_REL_STRUMENTI_SITI 
{
    public string COD_STUMENTO { get; set; }
    public decimal ID_SITO { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime DA_DATA { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime A_DATA { get; set; }
}
```

my linq query is

```
using (var cont = DALProvider.CreateEntityContext())
{

    var query =
    from cliente in cont.T020_CLIENTI 
    from sito
    in cont.T021_SITI
        .Where(s => s.ID_CLIENTE == cliente.ID_CLIENTE)
        .DefaultIfEmpty()
    from relStrumenti
    in cont.T520_REL_STRUMENTI_SITI
        .Where(s => s.ID_SITO == sito.ID_SITO)
        .DefaultIfEmpty()
    select new
    {
        clienteRec = cliente,
        sitoRec = sito,
        relStrumentiRec = relStrumenti
    };
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(aiFiltro.RAGIONE_SOCIALE))
        query = query.Where(i => i.clienteRec.RAGIONE_SOCIALE.ToUpper().Contains(aiFiltro.RAGIONE_SOCIALE.ToUpper()));
    var vRes = (from clienteDef in query

    select new ClienteFiltrato
    {
        RAGIONE_SOCIALE = clienteDef.clienteRec.RAGIONE_SOCIALE,
        ID_CLIENTE = clienteDef.clienteRec.ID_CLIENTE,
        COD_STRUMENTO = clienteDef.relStrumentiRec.COD_STUMENTO,
        DATA_DA = clienteDef.relStrumentiRec.DA_DATA,
        DATA_A = clienteDef.relStrumentiRec.A_DATA
    }) ;
    return vRes.AsQueryable();
}
```

but in my linq query i don't know where i can insert distinct and input parameter (:pPOD) to obtain my linq that in oracle query is:

```
SELECT DISTINCT t020.ragione_sociale,
                da_data,
                a_data,
                t020.id_Cliente,
                :pPOD
    FROM t020_clienti t020, t021_siti t021, T520_REL_STRUMENTI_SITI t520
   WHERE     t020.id_cliente = t021.id_cliente
         AND t021.id_sito = t520.id_sito
AND (:pPOD is null or t520.cod_stumento = :pPOD)
ORDER BY da_data
```

where :pPOD is an input parameter that i could have set or not.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add (s.COD_STUMENTO == pPod || pPod == null) to your Where clause, where you are filtering T520_REL_STRUMENTI_SITI entity. pPod should be a string variable.

Please have in mind that if you are using DefaultIfEmpty() in LINQ this will be translated to left join in SQL. 
Modified query follows:

```
string pPod = null;
using (var cont = DALProvider.CreateEntityContext())
        {

            var query =
            (from cliente in cont.T020_CLIENTI 
            from sito
            in cont.T021_SITI
                .Where(s => s.ID_CLIENTE == cliente.ID_CLIENTE)
                .DefaultIfEmpty()
            from relStrumenti
            in cont.T520_REL_STRUMENTI_SITI
                .Where(s => s.ID_SITO == sito.ID_SITO && (s.COD_STUMENTO == pPod || pPod == null))
                .DefaultIfEmpty()
            select new
            {
                clienteRec = cliente.Distinct(),
                sitoRec = sito,
                relStrumentiRec = relStrumenti
            });
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(aiFiltro.RAGIONE_SOCIALE))
                query = query.Where(i => i.clienteRec.RAGIONE_SOCIALE.ToUpper().Contains(aiFiltro.RAGIONE_SOCIALE.ToUpper()));
            var vRes = (from clienteDef in query

            select new ClienteFiltrato
            {
                RAGIONE_SOCIALE = clienteDef.clienteRec.RAGIONE_SOCIALE,
                ID_CLIENTE = clienteDef.clienteRec.ID_CLIENTE,
                COD_STRUMENTO = clienteDef.relStrumentiRec.COD_STUMENTO,
                DATA_DA = clienteDef.relStrumentiRec.DA_DATA,
                DATA_A = clienteDef.relStrumentiRec.A_DATA
            }).Distinct() ;
            return vRes.AsQueryable();
        }
```

You can use:

> string query =
>   ((System.Data.Objects.ObjectQuery)query).ToTraceString();
>   This will show you the generated SQL from LINQ Queryable object.

Comment: in this way if pPod=null query returns me a lot of RAGIONE_SOCIALE instead i would obtain distinct RAGIONE_SOCIALE

Comment: Just modified the LINQ queries. Added .Distinct() to the end vReq query.

Comment: i have tried but it doesn't work, distinct seems doesn't work

Comment: Just modified the LINQ queries. Added .Distinct() to query variable in the first query.

Comment: adding your code i cannot compile due to this error:  Error 33 'AnonymousType#1' does not contain a definition for 'Distinct' and no extension method 'Distinct' accepting a first argument of type 'AnonymousType#1' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: using ToTRaceString() when executing code gives this error unable to cast object of type 'System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery`1[<>f__AnonymousType1`3[AnagraficaDAL.Models.T020_CLIENTI,AnagraficaDAL.Models.T021_SITI,AnagraficaDAL.Models.T520_REL_STRUMENTI_SITI]]' sul tipo 'System.Data.Objects.ObjectQuery'. and query doesn't work because resault is not distinct

Comment: Modified the query a bit. Added clienteRec = cliente.Distinct(). Please try this.